# Copy 2d array into another

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I'm learning the C programming language from the book "C Primer Plus". I'm solving an exercise and I hit a wall:

> Write a program that initializes a two-dimensional 3×5 array-of-  double and uses a VLA-based function to copy it to a second two-dimensional array. Also provide a VLA-based function to display the contents of the two arrays. The two functions should be capable,in general, of processing arbitrary N×M arrays. (If you don’t have access to a VLA-capable compiler, use the traditional C approach of functions that can process an N×5 array).

I can't use VLA, as my compiler doesn't support it, I use VC2013. Here is my code:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIM1 10
#define LIM2 10
#define LIM3 2
int ct, ct2, size;

void copy_arr(double *[LIM3], double *[LIM3], int size, int lim);
int main(void)
{
    double arr1[LIM1][LIM2], arr2[LIM1][LIM2];

    printf("Enter the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Enter the array elements\n");

    for (ct = 0; ct < size; ct++)
    {
         for (ct2 = 0; ct2 < LIM3; ct2++)
         {
             scanf("%lf", &arr1[ct][ct2]);
         }
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (ct = 0; ct < size; ct++)
    {
        for (ct2 = 0; ct2 < LIM3; ct2++)
        {
            printf("%.2f ", arr1[ct][ct2]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    copy_arr(arr1, arr2, size, LIM3);

    for (ct = 0; ct < size; ++ct)
    {
        for (ct2 = 0; ct2 < LIM3; ++ct2);
        {
            arr2[ct][ct2] = arr1[ct][ct2];
            printf("%.2f ", arr2[ct][ct2]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n"); 

    system("pause");

}

void copy_arr(double (*arr1)[LIM3], double (*arr2)[LIM3], int size, int lim)
{
     for (ct = 0; ct < size; ct++)
     {
         for (ct2 = 0; ct2 < lim; ct2++)
         {
             arr2[ct][ct2] = arr1[ct][ct2];
         }
     }

return;
}
```

output: http://postimg.org/image/mnswuyy2b/

I can't figure out how to pass the value of the size variable to the function `copy_arr`.
Are there other ways except VLA?

Comment: You defined 2D array as `arr1[LIM1][LIM2], arr2[LIM1][LIM2]` but in loop you are using `LIM3` as limit of second dimension. Which one do you want??

Comment: Please don't include literal output text as an image (and if you *must*, at least use a provider that doesn't spam various pop-up windows). Just copy and paste the output in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr1[LIM1][LIM2]` is an array of size `LIM1` of arrays of size `LIM2`. Therefore the signature of `copy_arr` should be:

```
void copy_arr(double arr1[LIM1][LIM2], double arr2[LIM1][LIM2], int size, int lim);
```

or because C++ allows to omit the first dimension:

```
void copy_arr(double arr1[][LIM2], double arr2[][LIM2], int size, int lim);
```

or, because of array-to-pointer conversion, array can be converted to a pointer to array of size `LIM2`:

```
void copy_arr(double (*arr1)[LIM2], double (*arr2)[LIM2], int size, int lim);
```

You also have another problem in your code:

```
    for (ct2 = 0; ct2 < LIM3; ++ct2);
```

That last semicolon makes the following `{}` block not belong to the loop. Remove it.

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/NrhG96)

Comment: A semicolon how the hell didn't I saw it. It helped tnx.